# Responsive Bootstrap Issue - Mobile Site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to develop a mobile website.

Currently, I have a header that features the company logo on the left side of the screen and 3 navigation buttons on the right side.

I'm trying to get everything to resize responsively if the logo and nav buttons won't fit on the screen.

The logo resizes fine, but the 3 nav buttons wrap to new lines if the screen is to small.

How do I prevent this so they resize like the logo. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

See code below.

CSS:

```
  #topNavButtons
  {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      list-style-type: none;
      float: right;
  }

  #topNavButtons li
  {
      background-color: transparent;
      background-image: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      border-radius: 4px;
      float: left;
      padding: 0px 2px;
      position: relative;
  }
```

HTML:

```
    <nav>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <a href="#">
                <img style="padding: 10px;" class="img-responsive" src="logo.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="padding: 0px">
            <ul id="topNavButtons">
                <li style="background: red"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" style="display: inline-block" src="navButton1.png" /></a></li>
                <li style="background: green"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" style="display: inline-block" src="navButton2.png" /></a></li>
                <li style="background: blue"><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" style="display: inline-block" src="navButton3.png" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the logo image?

Comment: @Skelly 150 x 29px - Is it somthing to do with the dimensions of the logo image?

Comment: Where is the .row? Can't use the columns without a .row surrounding and not have issues with extra padding, remove those inline styles and use a .row so it clears too.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/yelig/1/edit**

Needs a width and you also need to use the structure of the grid system to prevent extra padding.

== HTML ==

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding-right">
     <a href="#">
     <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/150x29/000000/FFFFFF&text=LOGO" />
     </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-6">
     <ul id="topNavButtons">
        <li><a href="#">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x29/ba0404/FFFFFF&text=1" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x29/0474ba/FFFFFF&text=2" /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">
           <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/50x29/5b7c13/FFFFFF&text=3" /></a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

== CSS ==

```
topNavButtons {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.no-padding-right {
    padding-right: 0
}
#topNavButtons li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 2px;
    margin: 0 0 0 2px;
    width:33.333%; /* whether floated inline-block or whatever you need a width to scale down as the viewport sizes */
    max-width:50px;
}
#topNavButtons li img {
    margin:0 0 0 auto;
}
```